# Rename files by extracting a string from PDF files in Bash script

Tags: bash, file, pdf, rename

I have captured strings from multiple PDF files in a folder as follows.

`pdfgrep "To cite this article" *.pdf`

The output of which is as follows:

```
09592296.2016.1169809.pdf: To cite this article: T.G. Otte (2016) Black, J. (2016). Geopolitics and the Quest for Dominance,

14650040008407697.pdf:To cite this article: Stanley D. Brunn (2000): Towards an understanding of the

14650040600767859.pdf:To cite this article: Virginie Mamadouh & Gertjan Dijkink (2006) Geopolitics, International Relations

14650040802203927.pdf:To cite this article: Tristan Sturm (2008) Critical Methodological Geopolitics: Discourse Analysis/

14650040903141398.pdf:To cite this article: Sean Carter (2009) Geopolitics and the Screen: War, the Body and Violence,

14650045.2010.493996.pdf:To cite this article: John Agnew (2011): Capitalism, Territory and “Marxist Geopolitics”, Geopolitics,

14650045.2010.493997.pdf:To cite this article: Jeremy Black (2011): Towards A Marxist Geopolitics, Geopolitics, 16:1, 234-235
```

Now I want to pipe in a string from each of these lines as a filename to be supplied for renaming the file. For example,

File `14650040903141398.pdf` should be renamed as `Geopolitics and the Screen: War, the Body and Violence,`

I am clueless further on this.
thanks.

Comment: IMHO, you've gone down a bit of a rabbit-hole by searching in `*.pdf` because now you have to separate lines and filenames too. Maybe try starting with `for f in *.pdf; do ... done` then you have the filename already in `$f` and no filename to strip from the `pdfgrep` output.

Comment: Then look for a `sed` expression to replace everything up to a closing parenthesis with nothing.

Comment: Where does this part *Geopolitics and the Screen: War, the Body and Violence,* come from ?